# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, nuget-package

Using Visual Studio 2015 & Sitecore 8.0
I have created a new MVC project with .Net Framework 4.6.1, copied, and referenced the Sitecore.kernel.dll & Sitecore.mvc.dll.  Replaced the existing web.config & global.asax with the sitecore files.
Added a plain HTML page in the solution and tried to browse it (from VS). The page opens with this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This HTML page is not published to Sitecore yet. I'm guessing, the Sitecore.mvc.dll wants MVC 5.1.0 and the MVC in VS project is 4.0.

So, I tried the following steps.

1. Run install package command in package manager console for MVC 5.1.1 which shows the error

> Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

2. Deleted the `%AppData%\NuGet\nuget.config` and restarted VS2015
3. Manually browsed https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, but the page doesn't load - `Secure connection failed`. But this - http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json will promt to download the json. So, in the nuget changed https to http, but its the same error - Unable to load the service index...

I'm not even able to start my first Sitecore MVC project when this happens.

I replaced the sitecore web.config with the regular VS project's web.config and now I'm able to browse the page. I set its Copy To Output Directory to Do not copy, so that it will not get published.

Will I be able to proceed with my Sitecore development this way without any major issues in future.

Comment: Sitecore MVC depends on certain version of ASP.Net MVC. Your steps with trying install correct Nuget package are right. Your problem is with Nuget.... I am able to install MVC 5.1.1, access to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. As workaround you can get(and reference) right MVC assemblies from Sitecore installation folder. But right way: find out what is wrong with Nuget. (I guess that it could be firewall)

Answer (score 6):

You need to do a few things to fix this:

Your VS project should be updated to have the `web.config` file from the Sitecore installation. You *must* have the Sitecore version of that file or Sitecore will not run correctly

You should add a binding redirect for the MVC file that makes everything use the latest version:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    etc....
</runtime>
```

Make sure that the web.config file in your `/views` folder contains the correct versions of all the MVC assemblies. This is mine for a .net 4.6 application:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host
        factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="Sitecore" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Once that is done, your Sitecore installation should pick up the latest MVC binaries correctly.